# React.js "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

Tags: reactjs, json, api, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

*Here below are two pages login and protected and partial code is also attached. After login a token is generated, if user gets token then only user can see dashboard page. But i have been facing error, i.e "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

**view source**

```
 function Protected(props) {
5 |     const Cmp = props.cmp    
>7 |     var Auth =JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('auth'))
 | ^   8 |    console.log(Auth)
```

**view complied**

```
  5623 | function Protected(props) {
  5624 |   const Cmp = props.cmp;
 > 5625 |   var Auth = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('auth'));
   |                   ^  5626 |   console.log(Auth);
  5627 |   return /*#__PURE__*/react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.createElement("div", {
  5628 |     __self: this,
```

- 

**Login.js page**

```
export default class LoginScreen extends Component {
login(){
  console.log("state", this.state)
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/account/login',{
  method:'POST',
  body:JSON.stringify(this.state),
  headers:{
      'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
  },


 }).then((result)=>{
    result.json().then((resp)=>{
       console.log(resp.token);
       localStorage.setItem("auth", JSON.stringify(resp.token))
    })
 })


}
..........................
```

**protected.js page**

```
import React from "react";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

function Protected(props) {
 const Cmp = props.cmp   
 var Auth =JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('auth'))
 console.log(Auth) 
 return <div> { Auth ? <Cmp/> : <Redirect to="/"/>}
 </div>
}

export default Protected;
```

Comment: Can you please show me localStorage.getItem('auth') value because maybe this value is not JSON or get undefined.

Comment: localStorage.getItem('auth')
"\"4240256f255d22dd808720246a244bef1578dc00\""

Comment: I think you don't need to JSON parse. You can directly use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your localStorage.getItem('auth'); is not a JSON object,whenever you are trying to parse a a non-json object using JSON.parse you will ALWAYS get this error.(or if your object is undefined).So no matter what you do here it always will throw an error here.Your localStorage.getItem('Auth') is `"\"4240256f255d22dd808720246a244bef1578dc00\""`  which clearly isn't json object.You can add a check condition like below:

```
const isObject = (object: unknown): object is { [key: string]: any } => typeof object === "object" && object !== null;

if(isObject(localStorage.getItem('auth')))
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('auth'))
```

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage.getItem` might return undefined. if Item is not present in the local storage.

```
var _auth = localStorage.getItem('auth');

if(_auth){
    var Auth = JSON.parse(_auth)
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the auth item as an JSON, first delete the item from localStorage of your browser then change the code that save the item to look as below:

```
localStorage.setItem("auth", JSON.stringify({token: resp.token}))
```

then to retrieve it as a JSON you could first verify if the item exists so the code would be

```
var auth = localStorage.getItem("auth")
if(auth){
   var authItem = JSON.parse(auth)
   var token = authItem.token
   // do something with the token
}
```